# How to Divide the data in excel sheet which have different white spaces

Tags: java, excel

I am getting data from an Excel sheet using Java. I have to divide every line of the Excel sheet and store them into Arrays `Item1`, `Item2`, `Item3`, `Item4` respectively..

### Excel sheet

```
1.  Item1         Item2       Item3        Item4
2.  104F410       020544E0    1120D3614    HD434816N 43X48 16-MIC CLEAR Runas
3.  Promo 1343u   548548T     3465689634   HD404816N 40X48 16-MIC CLEAR
```

(etc)

I used the following code, but it is getting Items incorrectly like `Item2` and `Item3` as Item

```
    for (int realel = 0; realel < fouritems.size(); realel++) {
        System.out.println("4 elements can be splitted from   :" + fouritems.get(realel));
    }
    headitems2 = new String[fouritems.size()];
    int f = 0;
    for (int realel1 = 0; realel1 < fouritems.size(); realel1++) {
        headitems2 = fouritems.get(realel1).split("\\s+");
        try {
            Item1.add(headitems2[0]);
            System.out.println("Item1   :" + Item1.get(f));
            Item2.add(item1[1]);
            System.out.println("Item2  :" + VendorItem.get(f));
            Item3.add(items3[2]);
            System.out.println("Item3   :" + Item3.get(f));

            f++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: What is problem with `String.split("\\s+");`?

Comment: Just use a CSV parser (like http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: am dividing each item ie item1,item2 ......with spaces .......

Comment: Please consider second line of excel sheet
I have to  divide 
104F410 020544E0 1120D3614 HD434816N 43X48 16-MIC CLEAR Runas 


as Item1 = 104F410 and Item2 = 020544E0 and Item3 = 1120D3614 and Item4 = 43X48 16-MIC CLEAR Runas  and so on.... How it is possible

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago I used [Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents](http://poi.apache.org/index.html) to work with Excel files. You could use the API to get the data directly out of the sheet with the getStringCellValue of the Cell class. This worked very well will plain Excel sheets. If your Excel file contains a lot of fancy features or VBA code, then you may run into trouble.

Assuming, all your cells are formatted as Text/String, the code below will read the content of the Excel sheet. In the case, you have to read numeric values, you have to use getNumericCellValue() instead of getStringCellValue().

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class ReadFromXLS {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
    File xlFile = new File("MyInput.xls");
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(xlFile);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

    Row row = null;
    Cell cell = null;
    String value = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(100);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
      row = sheet.getRow(i);
      for (int j=0; j <= 3; j++) {
        cell = row.getCell(j);
        value = cell.getStringCellValue();
        sb.append(";").append(value);
      }
      System.out.println(sb.substring(1));
      sb = new StringBuffer(100);
    }
  }
}
```